How to get the correct camera name and Index in OpenCV on a laptop
I have created the following code in Python.
This is code that, when you select the name of a camera, displays the corresponding webcam video.
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
import cv2
from pygrabber.dshow_graph import FilterGraph
import threading


Builder.load_string("""
<TestWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            #DropDownList with kivy
            Spinner:
                id: devices_dropDownList
                text: 'Select Camera'
                values: '0:Cam1','1:Cam2'
                on_text: root.on_DropDownList_select(self.text)
           
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: ''
""")

class TestWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.openCvThread = None
        self.cameraIndex = 0

        #get devices
        device_list = []
        devices = FilterGraph().get_input_devices()
        for device_index, device_name in enumerate(devices):
            device_list.append(str(device_index) + ':  ' + device_name)

        self.ids.devices_dropDownList.values = device_list
    
    def on_DropDownList_select(self,text):
        if not self.openCvThread == None:
            self.openCvThread.join()
            self.openCvThread = None
            
        splitList = text.split(":")
        self.cameraIndex = int(splitList[0])
        self.openCvThread = threading.Thread(target=self.opencv_start)
        self.openCvThread.setDaemon(True)
        self.openCvThread.start()
        
    def opencv_start(self):
        capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.cameraIndex)

        while(True):
            ret, frame = capture.read()
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
            
        self.capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return TestWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()

When this code is built, the following GUI is displayed.

This code works fine on Windows desktop PCs.
However, when I tried this code on my Windows laptop, I got the Index and camera names out of sync.
This issue seems to be a problem among developers other than myself.
This appears to be a problem on the OpenCV side rather than a Python issue. However, I know that many webcam-based software such as OBS Studio can activate the correct index camera by selecting the camera name.
How can I map the correct camera name to the index in Python?

opencv does not offer a way to enumerate cameras or access them by a unique identifier. use a different library for this. I think Kivy has camera access methods.
